Prove that $\sigma_n(\widehat{L}) \geq \sigma_n(L)/2$.
I recently come across a problem with respect to singular value as follow.
Suppose $\sigma_n(L) \geq 2\|L-\widehat{L}\|$. Then $\|\widehat{L}\| \leq 2\|L\|$ and $\sigma_n(\widehat{L}) \geq \sigma_n(L)/2$.
I don't know how to prove the second conclusion $\sigma_n(\widehat{L}) \geq \sigma_n(L)/2$.
Does anyone have a solution which answers this question? Thanks in advance.

Is $\widehat{L}$ related to $L$ in any way?

Yes! Note that $L$ is a matrix with rank $n$.
